# Multiple WHERE conditions, count distinct ids and a conditional average SQL

Tags: sql, database, average, where-clause

I'm joining 3 tables that have repetitions of id (table 1), with labels (table 2) an time (table 3). They are joined on 2 different id columns that I do not need to select (org_id, pl_id).

I need to find distinct ids who, when title is 'Frost' and time is > 5000 seconds and then calculate how many of those distinct ids have a title of 'Doc' and a time of above average for that title.

The below attempt seems to filter on the WHERE clause except for the 'label', and I'm not sure how to calculate the average time with a condition for the id count..

giving me

```
id  title  label  time
1   Doc    blue   1000
2   Frost  green  6000
3   Frost  green  5500
4   Doc    yellow 5000
5   Doc    green  3000
```

What I need is:

```
  id  title  label  time
  1   Frost  green  6000
  3   Frost  green  5500
  5   Doc    green  3000
```

Any help much appreciated and happy to clarify anything.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vw.id, p.title, pl.label, vw.time
    FROM table1 vw
JOIN table2 p 
    USING(org_id)
JOIN table3 pl
    USING (pl_id)
WHERE (pl.label = 'green' AND p.title = 'Frost' AND time > 5000) OR (p.title = 'Doc')
ORDER BY vw.time DESC;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag would really help.  Your query -- which is much more complicated than the question suggests -- also references tables with multiple columns including "id".

Comment: edited with more information

Answer (score 1):

it seems you need  AND time > 5000 inside or

```
SELECT DISTINCT vw.id, p.title, pl.label, vw.time
    FROM table1 vw
JOIN table2 p 
    USING(org_id)
JOIN table3 pl
    USING (pl_id)
WHERE (pl.label = 'green' AND p.title = 'Frost' AND time > 5000) 
OR (pl.label = 'green' and p.title = 'Doc' AND time > 5000)
ORDER BY vw.time DESC;
```